# Short story about actors locked into unbreakable contracts that allow them to be injured, maimed, tortured, and killed

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

They are then healed medically and have to go through the whole process again. The audience uses buttons to vote on what happens next.

Comment: When did you read this? Was it a physical copy from an anthology, online, etc.? The overall description is good but can you remember any specific elements? If any?

Comment: It sounds very similar to this question https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/212105/short-story-where-tv-audiences-vote-on-the-plot-points-of-live-serials?r=SearchResults

Comment: @DannyMcG I was just going to propose that as the answer.  Do you want to do the honours?

Comment: Three minutes! That is awesome. Thank you very much. This is making research for our podcast much easier.

Comment: @ChefFrank thanks for confirming this, I've marked it as a duplicate of the earlier question.